# How does browser decides which port to connect to initially

Tags: browser, tcp

Suppose I have a Vanilla machine and this is the first time I am connecting it to Internet. There is no Cache at any level. I access a website through browser by typing example.com (no `http//:` or `https//:`). I am not telling the browser that it needs to connect on a specific port either. The first thing that will happen is that machine will resolve the domain name to IP and then a TCP Handshake will take place. There is no port negotiation that has happened yet then how does the browser knows which port to connect to?

I have gone through some articles on the web which states that HSTS will tell the browser which port to use as per the HTTP directive. But this does not explains how the browser decides on the port that it needs to connect to initially? How does the machine's OS knows which traffic is this (ICMP or HTTP). Is it always going to connect on port 80 or some other port first and then the sever would be able to tell which port it will listen on?

Answer (score 3):

If you don't enter a protocol (i.e. `http://` or `https://`) the browser will assume plain HTTP - unless the site is known to require HTTPS (i.e. [HSTS information preloaded](https://hstspreload.org/) with the shipped browser). If no port is given the default port of the protocol is used, i.e. 80 for HTTP and 443 for HTTPS.